Snyk Path Traverse Issue
I am getting the Path Traversal issue in snyk in my code below:
FileUtils.CopyFile(this.txtEnFileName.Text, fullEnPath, true, true);

I already have the code above that line to sanitize the inputs but when I re-scan, I'm still getting the same issue. I think Snyk wants me to modify the the line above itself. I'm not sure. Here's my actual code:
// Sanitize inputs
string sanitizedSubDirName = Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Aggregate(subDirName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty));
string sanitizedProduct = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(productList[count], (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty));
string sanitizedRootFileName = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(rootFileName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string. Empty));

// Combine paths safely
dstEnFileName = Path.Combine(sanitizedSubDirName, sanitizedProduct, sanitizedRootFileName + "EN.rtf");
dstFrFileName = Path.Combine(sanitizedSubDirName, sanitizedProduct, sanitizedRootFileName + "FR.rtf");

string fullEnPath = Path.GetFullPath(dstEnFileName);
string fullFrPath = Path.GetFullPath(dstFrFileName);

if (!fullEnPath.StartsWith(subDirName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || !fullFrPath.StartsWith(subDirName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Path traversal detected");
}

// Perform the file copy
FileUtils.CopyFile(this.txtEnFileName.Text, fullEnPath, true, true);
FileUtils.CopyFile(this.txtFrFileName.Text, fullFrPath, true, true);


What line fails? What's the exception? Does the fullPath exist? Does the source file exist?

It's not an error or an exception. The line FIleUtils.Copy is tagged as an issue in Snyk. regarding Path Traversal. Just need to modify the code so that Snyk won't tag it as Path Traversal issue.

Will you able to solve that? In my case for example if I do: filePath.Replace("..", "") is not tagged as issue, but if I encapsulate that in a function public static string SafeFilePath(string filePaht){ return filePath.Replace("..", "");} is tagged again as issue, which is weird.

it looks like you already have some good practices in place, but sometimes, the sanitization and validation steps are not sufficient to prevent all forms of path traversal attacks. You might want to double check that all parts of the path are sanitized properly. Also, have you checked for the full paths to ensure they are within the expected directory?
Another option is that Snyk might be flagging the FileUtils.CopyFile line because it directly uses user input. You can add additional checks to ensure the source files exist before copying.
Feel free to join the DevSecCon discord server for more answers. Plenty of users there to help you out https://discord.com/invite/WEV6pzq2C3

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
